# Method to check function declared or not in .dll file

Tags: dll, c++-cli, msxml6

Is there any tool by the help I can find whether a `function` is declared in `.dll` file or not.
Actually I am stuck in a problem where compiler is saying that it could not find the definition of `xyz method`.
Please if anyone know how can I check this thing,please Share.
I want to test `msxml6.dll`
Thanks

Comment: The most likely cause is a bug in your code, like declaring the function with an unmanaged function parameter or return value.  That makes it inaccessible to any other .NET language.  So checking if it is "declared" is not going fix anything.  Pretty pointless to force us to guess at this when you can just as easily post a snippet btw.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this specific  DLL but you can use  decompiler as IlSpy  (only if this is .Net dll) for reverse engineering the dll and check if the function is there.

**Update**
Now I see from the tags that this is C++ so decompiler won't help here.